# cross-(sub-)domain history.pushState (with CORS?)

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, cors, same-origin-policy, pushstate

Is it really not possible to use history.pushState over subdomains, even if using CORS? (I tried to configure NGINX to act that way, didnt seem to work). Shouldnt CORS tell the browser that it's okey to change the pushState to a subdomain, since the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is enabled (and that's the whole idea behind it)?
Did someone try it / made it work?

It would really be a shame if it's not, since I'm rather dependent on finding a solution for this problem to avoid reloads inbetween subdomains. Is there anything?

Comment: Since `history.pushState` does *not* fire a HTTP request, how do you think it could know whether CORS is allowed by that foreign server?

Comment: @Bergi is there another way to let it know, then? Or is it so fixed that you cant do anything at all? I dont get why they invent something like CORS, if it's not used by functions that follow the same-origin policy...

Comment: Well, CORS is a solution for *requests*, not for everything related to the SOP. I don't think it's possible to change domains in the location bar, but I also don't really see a reason to do that. What's your exact usecase?

Comment: @Bergi I have a valid use case for such behavior. I need to "retain" the URL in users' browser after a redirect (using mod_rewrite) from a.example.com to b.example.com to avoid their confusion (both sub-domains belong to the same org). Since I can't really _retain_ the original URL, I was looking for alternative solutions, such as DOM manipulation or, even, iframe or frameset with 1 px size (even though I don't like that), but the cross-domain security protection seems to be in the way. Since I don't need to make any requests, I'm wondering about whether CORS is even applicable. Any advice?

Comment: @Bergi To be more accurate, my redirect is from `a.example.com` to `b.example.com/groups/name`.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh You can try [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) for that, but really if you don't want a redirect then you should not do a redirect. Instead, *proxy* that directory so that it is served under both urls, and use a [canonical link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element).

Comment: @Bergi Appreciate your advice. I will try `document.domain`. In regard to proxy, I'm not sure, if this is applicable, as in my case `a.example.com` is not a real site, but just a domain name (DNS zone), used pretty much as an alias.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh The DNS doesn't have much to do with aliases. It's the server that serves the website for that domain who decides how to respond to requests. If you can do a mod-rewrite for that domain, you can also [activate a reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. However, the point of my previous comment is that there is **no** "server that serves the website for that domain". It is done at the _DNS zones_ level (at our org., anyway; and for this and maybe other FQDNs).

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Of course there is, it's the server where you currently have the mod_rewrite rule installed. The HTTP 301 redirect is not done by the DNS.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, you're talking about the destination domain. Sorry about the confusion. I'm still not sure how reverse proxy can help with retaining (an original / source) URL that user typed in the browser's address bar. After the redirect, it changes to the destination URL (as per rewrite rule). Could you elaborate?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh No, the server that responds with the redirect sits under the original domain. Just try it out to to make the rewriter a proxy! You might want to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), posting your configuration files (of the apache, and possibly the dns if you think it's relevant).

Comment: @Bergi Hmm, I think that there is a miscommunication between us. You seem to not realize the exact configuration (or I'm failing to explain it well enough). :-) Anyway, thank you, again, for your time and help. I will consider posting a separate question, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think Bergi's point is that your server has little to do with pushState, as it never reaches the server. The only time you would touch the server is when you refreshed the page.

A couple things could be happening.

1. You are trying to test this from a local environment with a browser that doesn't support it (i.e. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743).
2. You don't have your server configured to route your requests through to your index/app.

Can you provide some more information on your setup?